# Redis Session Callback Error

Tags: php, node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm trying to use Redis for the first time to share user authentication between php and node.js/Socket.io but I'm getting errors upon the initial setup. Anyone familiar with Redis who ran into similar problems?

Code available at https://gist.github.com/ecentinela/d8a5a8fa08868f633761

```
Warning: session_start(): Session callback expects true/false return value in C:\Apache24\htdocs\redis-test\redis-session-php\redis-session.php on line 46

Warning: session_start(): Session callback expects true/false return value in C:\Apache24\htdocs\redis-test\redis-session-php\redis-session.php on line 46

Warning: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: ) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\redis-test\redis-session-php\redis-session.php on line 46

{
    "_ga": "GA1.1.1281176092.1521216822",
    "_gid": "GA1.1.598584165.1530804160",
    "io": "3hiolWnr5DP2XkpRAAAD",
    "PHPSESSID": "rh67qig3e2vtda4kuk756gerl7"
}{
    "php": "Hello from PHP",
    "cookie": []
}
```

Comment: It would really be helpful if you shared some code related to the issue.

Comment: @nijm This is the code https://gist.github.com/ecentinela/d8a5a8fa08868f633761